# Как изменить принятие ссылки

Tags: javascript, html

`img src` принимает только те файлы которые находятся в той же папке с html, вопрос в том как сделать так чтобы `img src` начал рассчитать с папки `C://`

```js
let x = document.querySelector(".file")
let y =  document.querySelector(".img")
document.querySelector(".file").addEventListener("change",()=>{
        y.src = x.value
        console.log(x.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="file" class = "file">
        <img  class="img">
```

Comment: Попробуйте код из моего ответа тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208395/406363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let fileInput = document.querySelector('.file'),
        img = document.querySelector('.img');
        
fileInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const blob = new Blob([e.target.files[0]]),
                  url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  
     img.src = url;
});
```

```html
<input type="file" class = "file" accept="image/*">
 <img  class="img">
```

Comment: а без обьекта как можно?

Comment: тогда надо преобразовать картинку в base64 строку, но способ который я написал легче